# CORS issue with an ASP.NET Core Web API using app.UseEndpoints

Tags: asp.net-web-api, .net-6.0, middleware, blazor-webassembly

I create a new project Microsoft Visual 2022 with the template ASP.NET Core 6.0 Web API with use of controllers.

The endpoint is `https://localhost:7251/weatherforecast`.

I set my `program.cs`:

```
string? origins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(origins, builder => builder.WithOrigins("https://localhost:7041")
    .AllowAnyOrigin()
    .AllowAnyMethod()
    .AllowAnyHeader());
});
app.UseCors(origins);
```

Then I create a new project Microsoft Visual 2022 with the template Blazor Web Assembly App NET 6.0 without ASP.NET Core Hosted.

I write this basic call:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var response = await client.GetFromJsonAsync<WeatherForecast[]>("https://localhost:7251/weatherforecast");
```

...and it works.

Now, for some project requirements, I have to replace in my API.program.cs

```
app.MapControllers();
```

with

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
});
```

Then I get an error

> fetch is blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

For info, if the web app is a Client/Server/Shared, there is no problem.

How can I set the communication web app not hosted/API using endpoints?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I just had to add in the Program.cs of the API

```
builder.Services.AddControllers();
```

Not using the default client/server template in my web app makes me skip some behaviors and requires this line.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it's could be related your response headers. Can you try add this;

```
      app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            context.Response.OnStarting(() =>
            {
                context.Response.Headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*";
                context.Response.Headers["Access-Control-Allow-Credentials"] = "true";

                return Task.CompletedTask;
            });

            await next();
        });
```